# Mapping Entity To Model

Tags: c#, database, oop, mapping, structure

I have a struct with a string _description and List comments. How can I map them both so that it could happen something like this?

```
public IObjective MapEntityToModel(IObjectiveEntity objectiveEntity)
    {
        return new Objective
            (
                objectiveEntity._Id,
                objectiveEntity.Name,
                objectiveEntity.Description,
                objectiveEntity.Comments,
                (PriorityType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PriorityType), objectiveEntity.PriorityType)
            );
    }
```

As you can see, below the Description and Comments are two types for the struct where Comments is a List of strings. The error message displays that I don't have a constructor that takes 5 arguments, which of course is because I have defined a struct not a string and List of strings inside of the constructor of the Obective class. How should I proceed?

Comment: You need to be setting the fields of the struct rather than attempting to call a constructor.

Comment: have you tried to create a partial class?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public IObjective MapEntityToModel(IObjectiveEntity objectiveEntity)
    {
        return new Objective
            (
                objectiveEntity._Id,
                objectiveEntity.Name,
                new TaskDetails
                (
                    objectiveEntity.Description,
                    objectiveEntity.Comments
                ),
                (PriorityType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PriorityType), objectiveEntity.PriorityType)
            );
    }
```

Thank you all! I needed to call new TaskDetails and that is how it got fixed! :) That is how it works when moving out from database!